# Meaning of "CPU Usage" in Chrome Task Manager for "GPU Process"

Tags: google-chrome, gpu

In Google Chrome's Task Manager, there's a process GPU Process, and it has a CPU usage percentage like the other processes. Does "CPU Usage" actually mean GPU usage here, or is it CPU usage (meaning the GPU process also uses the CPU)?